# How to use two option menus in one toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I want to use two `OptionsMenu` in one `Toolbar`.

First optionMenu from `Activity`, and items from this menu must be on the end of `Toolbar`.

Second optionMenu from different `Fragment's`, (each has own menu) and must be before first menu.

This looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `Activity`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

In `res/menu/menu.xml` :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.nexttek.android.menu.activity.YourActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_one"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_one"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_image"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_two"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

By `app:showAsAction`, When and how this item should appear as an action item in the app bar. A menu item can appear as an action item only when the activity includes an app bar. Valid values,

- `always` :Always place this item in the app bar. Avoid using this unless it's critical that the item always appear in the action bar.
- `collapseActionView` :The action view associated with this action item (as declared by android:actionLayout or android:actionViewClass) is collapsible.
- `ifRoom` :Only place this item in the app bar if there is room for it.
- `never` :Never place this item in the app bar. Instead, list the item in the app bar's overflow menu.
- `withText` :Also include the title text (defined by android:title) with the action item.